# IE keypress event not firing for Enter key

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, keypress, enter

I'm trying to create a UI that allows a user to hit Enter to progress past most screens. This works great in most browsers, but seems to fail in IE.

I set up a JS Fiddle showing the behavior -- https://jsfiddle.net/fat9qy40/2/. It seems essential that there be some sort of form element that's hidden. In my actual use case, I pop up a div with some instructions and would like the user to be able to hit Enter to dismiss it -- there's still an underlying form beneath that div.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <button>
  Fake button
  </button>
  <div style="z-index:100;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;border:1px solid black;background-color:green;height:50px;padding:10px">
  Press enter to see an alert (unless you're using IE!)
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('keypress', function(e){
    alert(e.which)
})
```

In Chrome, if I click in the white space in the bottom right and then hit Enter, I get a popup that says "13", which is what I would expect. In IE 11, if I do the same thing, nothing happens. Other keypresses do properly fire the keypress event however; for instance, if I hit F, I get an alert that says "102".

Anyone have any workarounds or suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like this has been fixed in Edge but they are not back-porting it to IE. https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1552272/

Comment: If you use keydown or keyup instead?

Answer (score 0):

epascarello nailed it -- thanks! Strangely enough, I had thought to try keydown on my own, but it hit the same bug as keypress.

keyup, on the other hand, works great, and for my use case, I think it's just as good as keypress would have been.